# finding the intersection of a line with a non monotonic arbitrary surface?

Tags: matlab, graphics, computer-vision, raytracing

I have a surface Z on a X-Y grid for which I want to find the intersection point with a line. I used so far this code for finding the intersection:

```
x_ray = x_source + t * x_dir
y_ray = y_source + t * y_dir
z_ray = z_source + t * z_dir
height_above_plane = @(t) z_source + t * z_dir - interp2(X, Y, Z, ...
    x_source + t*x_dir, y_source + t*y_dir)
t_intercept = fzero(height_above_plane, 0);
```

my problem is that when my surface is "wiggly", the function has several zero crossing points, and I want to find the minimal out of them.
How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: What do you call a non-smooth surface ? How do you plan to interpolate it if it is "non-smooth" ? (Don't you confuse non-smooth and non-monotonic ?)

Comment: I interpolate it using interp2. it is not smooth in the sense that the line intersect the surface several times because the surface is "wiggly"

Comment: I wouldn't call that non-smooth.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to project the ray onto the XY domain and draw the corresponding Bresenham line. As you go along this line, grid cell per grid cell, you will compute the Z altitudes along the ray and check if their range overlaps the range of altitudes of the surface (i.e. the min and max value in this cell).

If yes, you have to find the 3D intersection between the ray and the interpolating surface, an hyperbolic paraboloid. If the intersection does fall inside the grid cell considered, you are done. Otherwise, continue the march along the ray.

Comment: Thanks, its a possible solution, but it will take too much time if I want to do it for millions of rays

Comment: If you know no particular property of the surface, you can't avoid this exploration. This is a Omega(N) problem, when N is the number of grid cells on a side.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the surface to matlab mesh, then use [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24484-geom3d/content/geom3d/meshes3d/intersectLineMesh3d.m).